# Twilio in-call dialing

Tags: php, twilio

So I am trying to creating a number that people can call to record the actual number they are trying to reach. Basically, call twilio number then dial number of person. I have a Twilio number set up but the php that I have made isn't dialing the numbers that the person is inputing. I probably am just missing something because I am at a below beginner level in php and have no idea what I'm doing. Here's the code for xml and php:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

    echo '<Response>';

    $user_pushed = (int) $_REQUEST['Digits'];

    if (numDigits==10)
    {
        echo '<Say>Calling</Say>';
        echo '<Dial record="true">';
        echo '<Number>$user_pushed</Number>';
        echo '</Dial>';
    }
    # @start snippet
    else if (numDigits!==10)
    {
        echo '<Say>I'm sorry</Say>';
        echo '<Say>Please try again</Say>';
        echo '</Hangup>';
    }

    echo '</Response>';
?>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather action="handle-user-input.php" numDigits="10">
        <Say>Please dial the area code and phone number you are trying to reach.</Say>
    </Gather>
    <!-- If customer doesn't input anything, prompt and try again. -->
    <Say>Sorry, I didn't get your response.</Say>
    <Redirect>handle-incoming-call.xml</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Comment: `echo '<Say>I'm sorry</Say>';` seems likely to mess up the string. Recheck that apostrophe.

Comment: If you want your users to interact / make phone calls with Twillio, a server-side language like php seems the wrong choice. You probably want the twilio.js library to handle everything in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

Have you tried just loading the `handle-user-input.php` file directly in the browser and seeing what happens.  You can simulate the parameters that Twilio would send by including them as querystring parameters:

```
handle-user-input.php?Digits=%2B1234567890
```

This would let you see echo'ed values or any error messages being generated by the PHP.

Quickly looking at your code sample, I see you're using a variable named numDigits but I don't see where its assigned a value.

Also, I don't beleive you need to cast the [Digits](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action-parameters) parameter to an `int` since it looks like all you are doing with it is using it in the TwiML output.

Hope that helps.